# How can I change the input keyboard layout while in the console?

Tags: linux, console

I need to change the layout of the keyboard while working in the console on Linux. I need to set up English layout as the default for the console. How can I do it?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu, logged under root

Comment: "loadkeys us" worked! How to make it default layout?

Comment: tl,dr copy+paste this: `setxkbmap us`

Comment: @J.Olufsen [How do I apply changes to the keyboard layout system-wide?](https://askubuntu.com/a/68863/1024340)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To change the system-wide keyboard layout, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

or edit the `XKBLAYOUT` line in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: On Red Hat 7: `localectl status`, `localectl list-keymaps`,`localectl set-keymap cz`, see [Changing the Keyboard Layout](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-changing_the_keyboard_layout) ... The keymaps are in `/usr/lib/kbd/keymaps/` btw..

Comment: Hi)) Ubuntu 18.04.2 with the Gnome desktop does not respond to the state `/etc/default/keyboard`. To change the keyboard settings in this case, you need to use `dconf`

Comment: How to enter a `-`? If i press `-` a `/` appears.

Answer (score 37):

To change your keyboard layout fast, just install setxkbmap with:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
```

After this you can always change the keyboard layout with:

```
setxkbmap us
```

To do this automatically every time, extend your `.bashrc` with:

```
echo "setxkbmap us" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now, open a new console and the US keyboard layout is activated.
Don't worry if the small keyboard layout icon in the Ubuntu panel does not change.

Comment: This does not really change the default keyboard layout but is a sort of hack to reset the keyboard layout to another one everytime you open a new console (while it is only necessary to reset after reboot). For a permanent solution, it is possible to set it directly, for example in `/etc/default/keyboard` like suggested by other answers.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.  setxkbmap(1) works under X (graphical) while OP asked about the console.  [OP even](https://superuser.com/questions/404457/how-to-change-input-keyboard-layout-while-in-console#comment460038_404457) brought up loadkeys(1) in a comment on his question, three years before you posted this answer (loadkeys(1) is a console-only program).

Answer (score 13):

Another way, but I understand it won't last for the next boot:

```
sudo loadkeys /usr/share/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.kmap.gz
```

Check `/usr/share/keymaps/i386/` for you keyboard layout and keymaps to what suits you better.

Comment: Put it in /etc/profile.d/bashrc

Comment: @BK, may be at `/etc/rc.local` to not require sudo?

Comment: `loadkeys us` (**without** the full path) is the only thing that worked for me on a system without *setxkbmap* (fresh minimal RHEL-8 install).

The full path differs between distros, on RHEL it's actually under `/usr/lib/kbd/keymaps` and there are 2 sets -- *legacy* and *xkb*.

Comment: Thank you. I have an embedded system (Toradex) with a minimal Linux image and I needed this to switch the keyboard layout to azerty.

Answer (score 8):

`loadkeys us`, it loads US keys but for a single  session.

Comment: Loadkeys has alrwsyd been suggested, and in better answers which included information on HOW to use it. Please avoid posting duplicate information in answers, especially when your posts does not actually consist of a complete answer.

Comment: Without `sudo`, I got `KDSKBMODE: Operation not permitted: could not switch to Unicode mode` ([Ubuntu&nbsp;19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine))).

Comment: 'loadkeys' might have been suggested. However, this answer worked. On the basic (sandboxed) Metasploitable the keymap directory is empty. BTW, 'man loadkeys' is very well written.

Answer (score 5):

On current systemd based systems use [localectl](https://manpages.org/localectl) (as mentioned by @david-tonhofer):

```
sudo localectl set-keymap us
sudo localectl set-x11-keymap us,de pc104
localectl status
```

Answer (score 2):

The very funny could be to switch back... a possible solution is, to make a Bash script (named with symbols of the target language. For instance, англ).

The second trick is to type "setxkbmap us; setxkbmap ru", and then it's possible to use the Bash history to return the main layout to the console.

Comment: Can you please clarify (1) what you’re saying, and  (2) how it answers the question?

Comment: well, you switched console in russian language. how would you like to switch it back to english 777 actually, i didn't answer main question, i just added some tricks to avoid possible problems. For example, you work w/o gui & switched console to russian, so you cannot type any command. :)

Comment: but what if— it defaults to ru?

Comment: @Fuseteam then a sleeper module in the linux kernel unlocks and it plays the russian national anthem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I'm gonna leave this in case someone else needs it. First answer is correct, it works, the only thing is that in newer versions the "keyboard" file doesn't exist, instead, we have a "console-setup" file where you can also find and edit the XKBLAYOUT option.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score 0):

A better hack is to monitor [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) and reset it automatically if the keyboard gets disconnected. Even users on laptops might need it, since it might get instantaneously disconnected. [I just made a GitHub repository to do this](https://github.com/equwal/xinput-persistence).

Comment: ***How*** do you monitor udev (respond by [editing you answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1428399/edit), not here in comments)?

Answer (score 0):

switch layout:

```
setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout ru,us
```

force switch:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```